# How can i add a new text label inside a return function on Yii2?

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to add a text label inside a return function on Yii2. Here is my code:

```
return function() {
    return [
        'main' => [
            [
                'alias' => 'siteName',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Site name'),
                'rules' => [
                    ['string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'alias' => 'siteAddress',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Company contact address'),
                'rules' => [
                    ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                    ['default', 'value' => ''],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'alias' => 'sitePhone',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Company contact phone'),
                'rules' => [
                    ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                    ['default', 'value' => ''],
                ]
            ],
  ];
};
```

and here is the HTML output:

Site Name

Company contact address

Company contact phone

How can add a new title after "Site name" so i can get this ?

Site Name

-- CONTACT SETTINGS--

Company contact address

Company contact phone

I already tried something like that:

```
return function() {
    return [
        'main' => [
            [
                'alias' => 'siteName',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Site name'),
                'rules' => [
                    ['string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
                ]
            ],
            [

                'label' => Yii::t('sk', '-- CONTACT SETTINGS --'),
                'alias' => 'siteAddress',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Company contact address'),
                'rules' => [
                    ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                    ['default', 'value' => ''],
                ]
            ],
            [
                'alias' => 'sitePhone',
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Company contact phone'),
                'rules' => [
                    ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                    ['default', 'value' => ''],
                ]
            ],
  ];
};
```

but didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try adding the new entry betwwen siteName and siteAddress ..

```
    return function() {
        return [
            'main' => [
                [
                    'alias' => 'siteName',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Site name'),
                    'rules' => [
                        ['string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'label' => Yii::t('sk', '-- CONTACT SETTINGS --'),
                    'alias' => 'siteAddress',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'rules' => [
                        ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                        ['default', 'value' => ''],
                    ]
                ],
                [
                    'alias' => 'siteAddress',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Company contact address'),
                    'rules' => [
                        ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                        ['default', 'value' => ''],
                    ]
                ],

                [
                    'alias' => 'sitePhone',
                    'type' => 'text',
                    'label' => Yii::t('sk', 'Company contact phone'),
                    'rules' => [
                        ['string', 'min' => 0, 'max' => 2048],
                        ['default', 'value' => ''],
                    ]
                ],
      ];
    };
```

But '-- CONTACT SETTINGS --' seems just an header to me and not a field so you should check for you code how manange header.

Comment: Thanks for helping @ScaisEdge. Exactly the --CONTACT SETTINGS-- is a header not a field. I just want to organize the menu.